# mixing css with c# mvc in razor

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I simplify this code using razor engine (c# mvc)..Is there any way to mix c# and css inside razor engine?

Actually i am not getting correct answer while trying this

```
 @model FoodViewModel

@foreach (FoodView item in Model.Foodviews)
{         
 @if (item.vote == 1)
       {
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="1"  checked="checked" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="2" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="3" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="4" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="5" />
       } 
        else if(item.vote == 2)
       {
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="1" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="2"  checked="checked"  />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="3" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="4" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="5" />
       }
       else if (@item.vote == 3)
       {
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="1" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="2" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="3" checked="checked" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="4" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="5" />
       } 

       else
       {
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="1" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="2" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="3" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="4" />
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="5"  />
       } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a simple loop?

```
@for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    if (i == item.vote) {
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="@i" checked>
    } else {
        <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="@i">
    }
}
```

Or, even better, with a html helper;

```
@for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
     @Html.RadioButton("example", i, item.vote == i, new { @class = "rating" })
}
```

Comment: where is conditioned checked?? in second answer?

Comment: @user3300195 the third parameter is a boolean (isChecked) -- by passing `item.vote == i` to it, the voted item will be checked.

Comment: hi i have slight problem,if 5 radio buttons are there for each item,then while displaying all item ratings, only one of item's rating is checking.Others are not checking

Comment: Sir,only last element is checked?while looping whether page reloads?

Comment: @user3300195 You need to have a unique value for the `name` property of each group -- in your post you only had `"example"`, but if you have an `id` (or `name` or similar) property on your `FoodView` object, you can use that instead. Or even append it: `@Html.RadioButton("radioButtonGroup" + vote.id, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Why not DRY up your code by trying something like:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
     <input type="radio" name="example" class="rating" value="@i" 
     @if(i == item.vote)
     {
       checked="checked"
     }
     />
}
```

Presumably you want some kind of label / value however?

Comment: Haha, +1 for pretty much the exact same thing I was writing :) I am not sure how well razor does in the middle of HTML tags though, which is why I wrote two `<input>`s -- are you sure it will work this way too?

Comment: i am getting data from database and also i need to generate multiple group of radiobuttons for rating each items